# Is it possible to play a streaming sound coming in from Bluetooth?

Tags: java, java-me, streaming, audio, bluetooth

Is it possible in from within a J2ME program to stream sound over a Bluetooth connection, for instance from a streaming server on another phone, or from a PC with a Bluetooth dongle?

Comment: Yes it is possible. cause you will find such functionality as inbuilt named "play via bluetooth" in some phones.

Comment: The question said "is it possible in J2ME"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this a few years ago using an SPP input stream and JSR 135, as described in funkybro's answer. The results (like most results using Bluetooth and J2ME) were inconsistent.  Some phones played the sound without issue.  On others, the playback skipped.  And, on some phones, it needed to receive the entire sound before it would play.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah should be.

Step 1 is to get hold of an `InputStream` over a Bluetooth connection, most likely using something like [SPP](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client/).

Step 2, pump that `InputStream` into a Player using JSR 135's [`Manager.createPlayer()`](http://bit.ly/mmFzM4).

HTH

Comment: Sounds reasonable and pretty easy, but whenever something looks easy in J2ME it is usually an illusion. :-)  I will try. Thanks!